# Can't specify the type of parameter to "then" handler

Tags: swift2, promisekit

If I specifiy the type of my parameter of a `then` handler as so...

```
.then { (things: [Thing]) -> Void in
```

then I get the error...

> Cannot convert value of type '[Thing] -> Void' to expected argument
>   type '(AnyObject) -> AnyPromise'

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting or do I need to cast the parameter in the body of the handler?

If you look [here](http://promisekit.org/introduction/) then the Objective-C code shows setting the parameter to an NSArray, which is, at least, not any object.

```
.then(^(NSArray *fetchedKittens){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must specify the required type using the promise's generic parameter.

```
public func MyAsyncFunction() -> Promise<[Thing]>
```

And its not necessary to type the parameter to the `then` handler.

```
.then { things -> Void in
```